# Kendo UI Grid Grouping and Paging with big data

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, grouping, paging, kendo-ui-grid

I have around 200.000 data and paging is set to 500.
The grouping function groups only data of paged items  and not of all which is in the database.

There are several posts regarding this matter, but did not find a proper solution / workaround

Telerik says it works as designed

I have also tried server grouping, same issue.

Do someone know a proper solution / workaround for my issue.

Some discussion regarding this issue:

[Grid group that spans multiple page](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-group-that-spans-multiple-pages)

[Grid with table hierarchy on for server grouping functionality](http://telerik.com/forums/grid-with-table-hierarchy-on-for-server-grouping-functionality)

Comment: I had a similar issue and ended up using this solution:  http://www.telerik.com/forums/slow-grid-performance-in-ie-linked-to-offsetwidth#Gqm21FQIFkeQvoRm-oCYjw